# Cobyla - how to define constraint with variable

Tags: c#, accord.net

I try to use Cobyla class from accord C# library for solving nonlinear optimization problem with constraints. It works correctly when the constraint is constant, for example:

```
NonlinearConstraint(2, x => x[0] + x[1] <= 100.0)
```

I need to use variable in the constraint (the value need to be changed by user), for example:

```
double limit = 100.0; 
NonlinearConstraint(2, x => x[0] + x[1] <= limit)
```

But it doesn't work. I get the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Accord.Math.dll

Can anyone show me examples how to properly define `NonlinearConstraint` with variable ?

Comment: This issue should finally have been fixed in version 3.7.0.